# Provision PVCs with correct zone information in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volume-claims, storage-class-specifier

I am doing a cluster backup and restore from GCP to Azure using [Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero)

The persistent volumes in k8s have `NodeAffinity` which has the zone and region selectors that don't match with the lables on the Azure node, because of the difference in zones/regions of the two GCP providers.

e.g. the following labels on nodes
GCP

```
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=australia-southeast1
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=australia-southeast1-a
```

and on Azure

```
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=australiaeast
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=1
```

So, I tried to create a `storage-class` in Azure like the following:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: fast-azure
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  cachingmode: ReadOnly
  kind: Managed
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - "1"
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
    values:
    - australiaeast
```

But when I try to create a PVC using this storage class, I get the following error:

```
arning  ProvisioningFailed    1s (x6 over 29s)   persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "fast-azure": compute.DisksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidAvailabilityZone" Message="The zone(s) '' for resource 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-105101ea-2c58-4a5a-8eeb-386c7489b782' is not supported. The supported zones for location 'australiaeast' are '1,2,3'"
```

Looks like it's reading a blank '' zone name. What's the correct way to write this storageclass for Azure?

Comment: did you try and change the value from `"1"` to `1`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It worked for me.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azure-disk
parameters:
  cachingmode: None
  kind: Managed
  zoned: "true"
  storageaccounttype: Standard_LRS
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - australiaeast-1
```